# On Passing a 2D-Array into a function

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is not so much a question on, "How do I pass it into the function?" but rather, "Is this acceptable?"

```
void func( int **ptr );

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
    int *pArr = *arr;

    (&pArr[0])[1] = 3;

    func(&pArr);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void func( int **ptr )
{
    cout << "In func()" << endl;
    ptr[0][1] = 5;
}
```

This works as far as I can tell. It doesn't really feel safe to me, but I like it more than passing a 2D array into a function. Instead, a pointer that does the work for me.

Would this be very confusing for people who had to read my code? Should I use other methods instead? Is it a bad idea to work with pointers to arrays?

Also, question a little bit off-topic. Why can I write:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *pArr = *arr;
```

but why can't I write

```
int arr[][3] = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
int *pArr = **arr;
```

or even use a **pArr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dissect this carefully, since array-to-pointer conversions are sometimes confusing.

```
int arr[][3] = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

`arr` is now an array of 3 arrays of 3 ints.

```
int *pArr = *arr;
```

`*arr` uses the array arr in expression, so it decays to a pointer to the first element of arr -- that is pointer to array of 3 ints (the array containing  {1,2,0}). Dereferencing that pointer (with `*`) gives you the array of 3 ints. Now you're using *that* array in an expression and it decays to a pointer to int, which is assigned to pArr.

```
(&pArr[0])[1] = 3;
```

`pArr[0]` gives the integer at which pArr is pointing (the number 1). `&pArr[0]` makes a pointer at that integer (which is actually equal to pArr). Indexing that pointer with [1] gives a reference to the next integer after the number 1, which is the number 2. To that reference you're assigning 3. Here's the catch: pointer to an element of an array can only be used to access other elements of the same array. Your pointer points at an element of the array {1, 2, 0}, which you've changed to {1, 3, 0}, and that's fine, but

```
func(&pArr);
```

Now you're creating a pointer to pointer to int (since pArr was a pointer to int), and passing that to your function.

```
ptr[0][1] = 5;
```

And now you've taken `ptr[0]`, which evaluates to the pointed-to object, which is your original pointer pArr. This line is equivalent to `pArr[1] = 5;`, and that is still valid (changing your {1,2,0} array to {1,5,0}). However, `ptr[1][...` would be invalid, because *ptr is not pointing at an element of an array of any kind*. It's pointing at a standalone pointer. Incrementing ptr will make it point at uninitialized memory and dereferencing that will be undefined behavior.

And for the additional questions:

You should not be able to write this:

```
 int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 int *pArr = *arr;
```

The array `arr` decays to a pointer-to-int (pointing at the number 1), dereferencing that gives the integer, and an integer cannot be assigned to the pointer pArr. gcc says *error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'*.
Likewise, you cannot write this:

```
int arr[][3] = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
int *pArr = **arr;
```

for the same reason: *arr is the array of 3 ints {1, 2, 0}, **arr is the integer 1, and an integer cannot be assigned to a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting confused here. `int arr[][3] = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};` is **not** a pointer to arrays of length 3. It's a single solid memory block 9 `int`s long, which decays into a single `int*`. The compiler does a 3*first+second mapping for you to this single block of memory.

The reason **the subscripting in the function is not valid** is because the function has no way of determining what the dimensions of the array are. With a single dimension array, you don't need this information -- you just add the index to the given base pointer. However, with a two dimensional array, you need the dimensions to calculate the final index.

`ptr[0][1] = 5;` in your function is being translated into `*((*(ptr + 0)) + 1) = 5;`, which is obviously not what you want given that `arr` is not an array of pointers.

EDIT: In response to comment:

> ptr[0][1] does overwrite the information in cell [0][1] of the array

Yes, you got lucky here -- here's why. When you passed the array into your function, you passed `(&pArr[0])[1]`, which is a pointer to a pointer to the first element of the array. When you did `*((*(ptr + 0)) + 1) = 5;`, `ptr+0` becomes a no-op, leaving `*(*ptr + 1) = 5;`, which does have well defined behavior given your input data (it's looking at `arr` as a single-dimension array). If you'd try to change the first dimension of the subscript, however, it would blow up.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I'm not quite understanding what you mean. ptr[0][1] does overwrite the information in cell [0][1] of the array, so how is that not what I want? 

And then, if the array is simply a block of 9 units, then could I really use a pointer that simply points to element 0..7 of the array instead of doing this? So I basically overcomplicated the entire thing?

Comment: @SoulBeaver: Yes. `arr` decays into an `int *`, not an `int **`. I have responded to the first part of your comment in my answer.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because both the answer and the answerer's comment about the decay is wrong. `arr` is not a pointer to memory, but it is a memory block itself (if it were a pointer, it wouldn't need a decay). And it decays to `int(*)[3]`, not to `int*`. To the question, i wanna say that whole `(&pArr[0])[1]` thing is just the same as `pArr[1]`. I suspect he wanted to write `(&pArr)[0][1]` to simulate the access done in the function. But his whole code does not make sense to me. I suspect he is deeply confused. Please correct the answer and i will retract my downvote, mate.

Answer (score -1):

I find multi-dimensional arrays in C++ always a bit confusing and tend to avoid them. There are several solutions that are easier to understand, such as the classes in the Boost.MultiArray or Boost.UBlas libraries, or a vector of vectors, depending on your needs.